# Memory leaks in Angular JS

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, memory-leaks

Memory leaks that occurs in IE9 when using ng-view. It seems that when i clean the memory before navigating and after navigating, this memory issue will not occur.

We narrowed it down to the essential code over here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6181994

Does anybody know if Angular team addresses that issue?

Happens in Angular 1.1.5

Comment: Look at the git issue for angular.

Comment: i have used ng-view with IE9 without any issues i dint face any issues.Issues might be related to any of your controllers and too many watchers

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal the code provided shows the problem exist.You can validate the problem using the provided code.